# Circular Reference Error with an INDEX and MATCH function within IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I keep running into a circular reference problem (displayed at bottom left of screen) for values under "Mold ID Num" as well as other quirky errors such as not propagating my formula throughout the column in a table and more.

The code below is meant to return values from they "Mold ID" column if the are within 15 days and are a distinct value (so unique as well as 1st iteration of a duplicate) and create a list under "Mold ID Num" on a different sheet. Seems to work ok much of the time too however.

```
{=IFERROR(IF('Raw Data'!B2>=TODAY()-15, INDEX(Table5[Mold ID], _
MATCH(0, COUNTIF( Table2[[#All],[Mold ID Num]], Table5[Mold ID]),0)), ""), "ERROR")}
```

Table5:

```
  B             C           D
1 Start Day     End Day     Mold ID
2 10/16/2016    10/17/2016  T-65-001
3 10/16/2016    10/17/2016  T-579-001
4 10/14/2016    10/15/2016  T-1751-001
5 10/14/2016    10/15/2016  T-1226-001
6 10/14/2016    10/15/2016  T-E35-001
7 10/14/2016    10/15/2016  T-9025-001
```

Thanks for any help

*if anyone feels like explaining how to make a table automatically expand and contract (i.e. add and delete rows) when updating a formula in one column (the one above) that returns a different number of rows each time it is run, that would be incredible too*

EDIT1

Table 2:

```
   B                 C          D           E            F
19 Mold ID Num       Max        Completed   Progress Bar Remaining
20 T-965-001         150,000    200         0%           149800
21 T-9579-001        100,000    490         0%           99510
22 T-1751-001        100,000    26967       27%          73033
23 T-1826-001        200,000    13310       7%           186690
24 T-AP35-001        90,000     500         1%           89500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found to work in the end.

`=INDEX(IF(Table5[Start Day]>=TODAY()-30,Table5[Mold ID], ""), MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($B$19:B19, IF(Table5[Start Day]>=TODAY()-30, Table5[Mold ID],1)),0,0), 0))`

Using Crtl+Shift+Enter to confirm the formula.
thanks for the help @maxhob17

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is something like the following, I have put this formula in cell H2 so you will need to update the "$H$1:H1" bit in your MATCH function:

```
{=INDEX(Table2[Mold ID],SMALL(IF((Table2[Start Day]>=TODAY()-15)*ISERROR(MATCH(Table2[Mold ID],$H$1:H1,0)),ROW(Table2[Mold ID])-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[Mold ID]])),1))}
```

Comment: thanks, but couldn't get it to work. Doesn't seem to filter by the date and also returns multiple (like 40) instances of the same value "Mold ID Num" column is not in Table5, could this be a cause for the formula not to work?

Comment: I forgot to mention the above formula should be entered as an array formula, so Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of just Enter.

Comment: Also, did you remember to update the "$H$1:H1" part for you purposes? H1 in this case is the header row which would have "Mould ID" in it

Comment: `=INDEX(Table5[Mold ID],SMALL(IF((Table5[Start Day]>=TODAY()-15)*ISERROR(MATCH(Table5[Mold ID],Table2[[#Headers],[Mold ID Num]],0)),ROW(Table5[Mold ID])-ROW(Table5[[#Headers],[Mold ID]])),1))`

This is the code I used. It results in only one value, repeated forever, in "Mold ID Num" Column

Comment: Can you show me what Table2 looks like? You will need to manually type out the cell references e.g.` $H$1!$H1` for the the bit in the MATCH function as opposed to the Table reference `Table2[[#Headers],[Mold ID]] `you currently have. This part if the code checks if the current Mold ID

Comment: (sorry hit add too early) ... checks if the current Mold ID appears in the cells above

Comment: Using the normal cell references instead of the Table syntax displays distinct values (until a point) and does not throw any Circular Reference errors. However, at about row 68 one value repeats forever. This value is not the last distinct value in the list either. Code being used: `=INDEX(Table5[Mold ID],SMALL(IF((Table5[Start Day]>=TODAY()-30)*ISERROR(MATCH(Table5[Mold ID],$B$19:B20,0)),ROW(Table5[Mold ID])-ROW(Table5[[#Headers],[Mold ID]])),1))`

Comment: **The above comment should have `$B$19:B19` in MATCH function 

I encounter a similar situation with this formula that I have also tried a few times: `=INDEX(Table5[Mold ID], MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIFS($B$19:B19, IF(Table5[Start Day]>=TODAY()-30, Table5[Mold ID],"")),0,0), 0))` the repetitive value issue occurs at a different value